# Html Canvas sitting at different width of css

Tags: html, css, canvas, attributes, settings

When I click on the button of my application to generate the canvas, it is setting a different size from the correct CSS Style. Does anyone know what they can and can help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NgZe.png)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Yes, please add the HTML and JavaScript for the button.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. I can see your code in the image you have provided (and have put up an answer based on that) but on SO it is best, and you will get more interest from people who can help you, if you can put up a snippet of code in the actual question so that we can try for outselves. This [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example should help you next time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image of your code I can see that you have the attribute width of the canvas set differently from the CSS style setting.

The two do not have exactly the same meaning (as you have discovered).

Here's the recommendaion from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas):

> Sizing the canvas using CSS versus HTML
>
> The displayed size of the canvas can be changed using CSS, but if you
> do this the image is scaled during rendering to fit the styled size,
> which can make the final graphics rendering end up being distorted.
>
> It is better to specify your canvas dimensions by setting the width
> and height attributes directly on the  elements, either
> directly in the HTML or by using JavaScript.